# How to Pass Array From Form Load to Button Click Method

Tags: c#

New C# user. I understand global variables are not part of C#. Been trying learning properties, set and get. But I have what must be a common situation and I can't find the answer. This is what normally seems to happen when I design a form:

```
...
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {         
...
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {....Label[]  labelsArray = { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };...
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
...
}
...
```

So I made a "`labelsArray`" in `Form1_Load` that I want to use in the `button1_Click`. But I cannot - "Error    1   The name 'labelsArray' does not exist in the current context".

I do have access to the labels in `button1_Click` and I suppose I can re-declare the array and it'd work. But seems like I should be able to pass the array from Form1_Load to button1_Click and use it. But I'm lost after trying many things. How is it done please?

Thanks

Comment: Declare your label[] globally outside Form Load method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to declare the variable outside the methods like:

```
private Label[]  labelsArray = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   labelsArray = new Label[]{ label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

Comment: We're not writing VB6 code anymore, .NET supports constructors.  The *labelsArray* initialization belongs in the constructor, after the InitializeComponent() call.

Comment: The array just contains references, they are initialized by the constructor.

Comment: No, they are not null after InitializeComponent().  Intentionally putting initialization code in the Load event makes programs *slower*.  It defeats the bulk initialization that Winforms can use when it knows how to initialize the native window up front.  The Load event is only necessary when you need to know the Location and Size properties.  Thinking that Load is "special" is cargo cult, it came from VB6 and got re-inforced by the designer making the event the default event.  It is very hard to root out.  What you ultimately failed to show is how using the constructor could be wrong.

Comment: If you don't have enough info then always post correct code.

Comment: Thanks, but can't figure out. I tried exactly what cited in answer1 and get errors - so I tried the following and get one error. I do: private Label[]  labelsArray = null; were you say, then after some tries I do: labelsArray = new Label{ label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 }; and get the error: Error 1 Cannot initialize type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'    Be grateful for help...

Comment: @user1325143 the initialization is from your sample code.. The issue described was about the scope of the variables not their initialization but now that you highlight it, it should be `new Label[]{ label1, label2, etc...};` see the updated answer

Comment: Absolutely and I thank you for sharing your skills and knowledge!